# The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters

Tags: java, sql-server, sql

Este es parte del código, la lista ids presenta 3000 elementos.

```
SQLQuery query = super.getSession(false).createSQLQuery(selectString + fromString + orderBy);   

query.setParameterList("ids", ids);
registros = query.list();
```

....

Cuando se ejecuta la consulta sale el siguiente error:

> **The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters. Reduce the number of parameters and resend
>   the request.**

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: que servidor de sql usas? MYSQL, MONGODB, MSSQL, MARIADB?

Comment: Utilizo servidor MSSQL

Comment: aparentemente el maximo de parametros por consulta soportados son 2100 en MSSQL, y creo que esto no puede ser modificado, te aconsejo que en este caso hagas 2 arrays de ids, asi envias 1500 y 1500 y ejecutas 2 consultas de lo contrario lo veo complicado.

Comment: El problema es que está asignando un parámetro por cada id. Lo que necesitas es enviar todos como una tabla para que así los reciba la consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Como describe el mensaje de error, relacionado a Microsoft SQL Server

> [La secuencia de protocolo de llamada a procedimiento remoto (TPC) de
>   flujo de datos tabulares entrantes (TDS) es incorrecta. Se
>   proporcionaron demasiados parámetros en esta solicitud RPC. El máximo
>   es 2100.](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/6160)

Solución:

> Disminuya el número de parámetros a un número permitido por la base de
>   datos de SQL Server.

**Realiza la consulta en bloques de elementos que sean menores a 2100, de esta forma podrás evitar este problema.**